# Vue-cli on android - cannot call any endpoint from my local node server

Tags: android, node.js, vue.js, cors

I'm developing a Vue-cli + Node (express) application, Vue-cli is running on port 8080 and my node server in port 3001, both on localhost.

When I test my app in my desktop it works just as expected, I can navigate the entire app without issues, the problem appears when I test it on android, for all request the frontend does to the backend I get this error whether using fetch or axios:

```
<whatever rest verb> https://localhost:3001/<whatever endpoint> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My axios instance:

```js
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://localhost:3001',
  withCredentials: true
});
```

And this is the relevant node server configuration:

```js
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://<my local ip>:8080',
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // <-- this is located before any other express middleware
```

I'm setting credentials in both part because I'm using passportjs and cookie-session to handle login, but this issue is present even in a simple GET request, also I already tried without setting credentials but the issue persists.

- Axios version 1.2.1
- cors middleware version 2.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the local ip (as oppose to `localhost`) also in the baseUrl for the axios instance:

```js
const options = {
  baseURL: 'https://<your local ip>:<your api's server port>',
  withCredentials: true
}
```